# Is possible to cipher keys in the .juju/environments.yaml file?

Tags: juju

Is possible to have a **~/.juju/environments.yaml** file like this?:

```
environments:
  sample:
    type: ec2
    access-key: $(cat access-key)
    secret-key: $(cat secret-key)
    control-bucket: juju-8b53699f85c0438c96897ce75f633aa1
    admin-secret: 9a7c512f938f4bafb96365d7ceaf569b
    default-series: precise
    ssl-hostname-verification: true
```

I'd like to get those keys from gpg output or something which let me cipher them, so I can put the file on Internet and nobody could be able to use my ec2 account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are YAML files not bash, as such they are taken as string key => value assignments under normal YAML rules. If you're going to post your configuration file on the internet before sure to first blank the access-key and secret-key fields

Comment: I'd prefer to integrate the keys there so I can forget about them, anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You'll want to open a feature request against the project then

Comment: I've just file it, https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1131038 , thanks Marco!